Why is で used with タイミング instead of に?
The norm is to use the で particle with タイミング for "at a ... time", here are some examples.
Normally the に particle marks points in time (8時に, 火曜日に, 10月に...), although で can also do this with a sense of finishing/completing/ending (「来月で卒業する」「仕事が昨日で終わった」「タバコを今日でやめる」etc) but I don't see that nuance implied here with タイミング.  So what use of the で particle is this?

Sounds like you answered your own question.  "Timing" is not a specific point in time...

You're correct that タイミング almost always takes で:

それを見たときに答えに気付いた。
それを見た瞬間に答えに気付いた。
それを見たタイミングで答えに気付いた。

Ultimately, you may have to remember this as a rule (we say ～した後で for whatever reason). One explanation would be that タイミング is perceived not as a time point but as a "condition" or "situation", and で is chosen as a more generic condition marker.
